# Decision problem related to coloring

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np-hardness, graph-colouring

Given a $k$-colorable graph $G$ and vertices $u$ and $v$ of $G$, what is the complexity of deciding if every $k$-coloring of $G$ must assign the same color to both $u$ and $v$?

It does not seem obvious to me how to use the above problem as an oracle to construct a coloring, so it is conceivable that this problem is efficiently decidable.  On the other hand, minor variants of NP-hard problems, such as this one, typically remain NP-hard.  But most of all, I do not know what problem is a good choice to reduce from.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Add the edge $(u,v)$. Your property holds if and only if $G$ is still $k$-colorable.

Comment: Ah, very good. Will you make this an answer?

Comment: You should specify that they should take the same color _in every k-coloring_. Otherwise, the problem is not interesting.

Comment: @Austin Yes, this is what I meant. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the edge $(u,v)$. Your property holds if and only if $G$ is no longer $k$-colorable.

Comment: Let $G$ be obtained from the complete graph with $n$ vertices by deleting the edge $uv$. Then $G$
is $(n-1)$-colourable and every $(n-1)$-colouring of $G$ must assign the same colour to both $u$ and $v$. But $G$ plus the edge $(u,v)$ is not $(n-1)$-colourable.

Comment: There was a mistake in the original answer. The current answer should work.

Answer (score 3):

If you can solve this problem, it implies a coloring algorithm for [Uniquely colorable graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniquely_colorable_graph).

Though, I'm not sure the problem of coloring uniquely colorable graphs is NP-hard.

Comment: [Unique 3-Colorability is as hard as Unique Satisfiability](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1013869)

Comment: @AustinBuchanan According to Barbanchon's paper Unique 3-colorability is DP-complete under polynomial time randomized reductions. Does that imply that the problem is NP-complete? (I suppose not). If I understand it right, randomized reductions does not prove hardness, but rather gather practical evidence for hardness.

Comment: By the way, given a graph $G$ and a $k$-colouring $f$ of $G$, it is NP-complete to test whether $f$ is the unique $k$-colouring of $G$ (upto permutation of  colours) [Dailey, 1980] (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X80902368).